# Deserializing json C# unexpected character encountered

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net

Not sure where I'm going wrong here. Serialized an object with newtonsoft to post to a web api. Running into error: "unexpected character encountered"

Here's my json:

```
{
"Eve": "wizz",
"familyid": "1006949",
"time": "07/21 05:45:59 AM",
"DogName": "Rocky",
"userid": "1006949"
}
```

Deserialize:

```
BtnData listObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BtnData>(json.ToString());
```

Model:

```
   public class BtnData
    {

        [JsonProperty("Eve")]
        public string Eve { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Familyid")]
        public string Familyid { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Time")]
        public string Time { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("DogName")]
        public string DogName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Userid")]
        public string Userid { get; set; }
    }
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult AddEvent([FromBody] BtnData json)
```

Comment: The class appears fine, running this in a console app deserialises the JSON into the object correctly.  Are you sure the JSON is being posted correctly?

Comment: i just tested your code and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Liam, I thought the same as you. But I just tried here and worked. Maybe the Newtonsoft.Json version 12.0.3 is case-insensitive?

Comment: Seems your right @D.Kastier

Comment: Looks like we need a [mcve] then

Comment: can you post full error?

Comment: I am using json serializer to serialize the object before placing it in a post call to a web api

Comment: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: D. Path '', line 0, position 0.'" -full error

Comment: As said it's indeed working, are you sure you passing this JSON? maybe you have root in the JSON you missed?

Comment: I'll have to continue you digging into it. I've been on it for a few hours now. I've tried the json via postman, so I'm sure there is no root missing.

Comment: you can rule out case sentivity by changing the name of the JsonProperty attribute in btnData object to match the json data.. like this    public class BtnData
    {

        [JsonProperty("Eve")]
        public string Eve { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("familyid")]
        public string Familyid { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("time")]
        public string Time { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("DogName")]
        public string DogName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("userid")]
        public string Userid { get; set; }
    }

Comment: `json` is already deserialized for you (it does that for you since you declared `[FromBody] BtnData json`. When you call `ToString()` on it it falls back to the default implementation which, for a class, just prints the name of it's type. And this name is invalid json so deserialization fails.

Comment: @Knoop awesome answer !

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by @knoop. Thank you !

json is already deserialized for you (it does that for you since you declared [FromBody] BtnData json. When you call ToString() on it it falls back to the default implementation which, for a class, just prints the name of it's type. And this name is invalid json so deserialization fails